# How to use zsh by default for terminal emulator

Tags: neovim

In neovim, when use the command `:term`, it opens a new shell with `bash`. I want to use `zsh` by default.

`zsh` is already my default shell. I changed it with `chsh`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looking at [`:h :terminal`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/various.html#:terminal) it says

> Execute {cmd} with 'shell' in a new terminal buffer

So use `:set shell=/path/to/zsh`. Put it in your vimrc file (probably *init.vim*) to make it "permanent".

Comment: I keep getting `An unknown element "" was received.`. Are there other settings that should go with this?

Comment: What's emitting that? Vim? Zsh? I've never seen that message before. If you don't have any more information I suggest you swap out your vimrc for a bare bones version with not much more than the `set shell=...` line and see what happens. And running vim with `-V` will tell you what's going on during startup.

Comment: I have been having this issue as well, and it's a couple of plugins that are emitting the message (vim-plug and ctrlp.vim so far). It seems to have something to do with using powershell. https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/System.Management.Automation/resources/RemotingErrorIdStrings.resx#L782

Removing the "set shell" directive from my vimrc stops them from occurring. Still haven't figured out what's going on.